# Using Mapper.Initialize in constructor

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using AutoMapper to map my POCOs to DTOs.
For Unit testability, I am passing IMapping engine into my constructor and using Mapper.Initialize in case of constructor is null.

```
public class PeopleEfProvider : IPeopleDbContext
{
    public IMappingEngine MappingEngine { get; set; }
    public DatabaseHelpersRepo DatabaseHelpersRepo { get; set; }
    public PeopleDataContext DataContext { get; set; }
    public PeopleEfProvider(PeopleDataContext dataContext = null, IMappingEngine mappingEngine = null)
    {
        DataContext = dataContext ?? new PeopleDataContext();
        // if mappingEngine is coming from Unit Test or from another Client then use it.
        if (mappingEngine == null)
        {               
            Mapper.Initialize(mapperConfiguration =>
            {
                mapperConfiguration.AddProfile(new PeopleEfEntityProfile());
            });
            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
            MappingEngine = Mapper.Engine;
        }
        else
        {
            MappingEngine = mappingEngine;
        }
        DatabaseHelpersRepo = new DatabaseHelpersRepo(DataContext, MappingEngine);
    }
}
```

Is there any downside using AutoMapper this way? I run my integration test over 1000 loop and did not see any issue, on the other side I cannot say if it will be feasible when I put it online.

Will AutoMapper try to construct all mappings from scratch on next object creation or is it smart enough to not to map same objects again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mapper.Initialize should be called only once per AppDomain, you'll have some wonky threading issues if you don't just call it at application startup (App_Start etc).

You could also create a lazy initializer to accomplish the same thing:

```
public class PeopleEfProvider : IPeopleDbContext
{
    private static Lazy<IMappingEngine> MappingEngineInit = new Lazy<IMappingEngine>(() => {
        Mapper.Initialize(mapperConfiguration =>
        {
            mapperConfiguration.AddProfile(new PeopleEfEntityProfile());
        });
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        return Mapper.Engine;
    });
    public IMappingEngine MappingEngine { get; set; }
    public DatabaseHelpersRepo DatabaseHelpersRepo { get; set; }
    public PeopleDataContext DataContext { get; set; }
    public PeopleEfProvider(PeopleDataContext dataContext = null, IMappingEngine mappingEngine = null)
    {
        DataContext = dataContext ?? new PeopleDataContext();
        MappingEngine = mappingEngine ?? MappingEngineInit.Value;
        DatabaseHelpersRepo = new DatabaseHelpersRepo(DataContext, MappingEngine);
    }
}
```

Comment: Lazy initializer will help me a lot in this instance. I do not want to move all my mapping configuration into App_Start, then classes which are not aware of that configuration, will fail for all my unit/integrationt test. I should not forget to configure AutoMapper before I run my tests. Constructor injection reminds me about that dependency.